# How to avoid Rspec shared examples 'previously defined' warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, warnings

I am trying to learn how to use Rspec's shared examples feature and am getting a warning when I run my tests:

```
WARNING: Shared example group 'required attributes' has been previously defined at:
  /Users/me/app/spec/support/shared_examples/required_attributes_spec.rb:1
...and you are now defining it at:
  /Users/me/app/spec/support/shared_examples/required_attributes_spec.rb:1
The new definition will overwrite the original one.
....
```

I have read what I think is the documentation on this problem [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) but I'm having trouble understanding it/seeing the takeaways for my case.

Here is my shared example:

```
# spec/support/shared_examples/required_attributes_spec.rb

shared_examples_for 'required attributes' do |arr|
  arr.each do |meth|
    it "is invalid without #{meth}" do
      subject.send("#{meth}=", nil)
      subject.valid?
      expect(subject.errors[meth]).to eq(["can't be blank"])
    end
  end
end
```

I am trying to use this in a `User` model and a `Company` model. Here is what it looks like:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  subject { build(:user) }
  include_examples 'required attributes', [:name]
end

# spec/models/company_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

describe Company do
  subject { build(:company) }
  include_examples 'required attributes', [:logo]
end
```

Per the recommendations in the Rspec docs I linked to above, I have tried changing `include_examples` to `it_behaves_like`, but that didn't help. I also commented out `company_spec.rb` entirely so there was just one spec using the shared example, and I am still getting the warning.

Can anyone help me see what's really going on here and what I should do in this case to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found the answer in this [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/828) at the Rspec Github:

> Just in case someone googles and lands here. If putting your file with
>   shared examples into support folder has not fixed the following
>   error...Make sure your filename does not end with `_spec.rb.`

Answer (score 1):

As a followup to this, I had the issue in an included shared context with a filename that did *not* end in `_spec.rb` and was manually loaded via `require_relative`, not autoloaded. In my case, the issue was a copy-paste problem. The test looked like this:

```rb
RSpec.shared_examples 'foo' do
  RSpec.shared_examples 'bar' do
    it ... do... end
    it ... do... end
    # etc.
  end

  context 'first "foo" scenario' do
    let ...
    include_examples 'bar'
  end

  context 'second "foo" scenario' do
    let ...
    include_examples 'bar'
  end
end
```

The intent was to provide a single shared set of examples that exercised multiple contexts of operation for good coverage, all running through that internal shared examples list.

The bug was simple but subtle. Since I have RSpec monkey patching turned off (`disable_monkey_patching!`), I have to use `RSpec.<foo>` at the top level. But *inside any other RSpec blocks*, using `RSpec.<foo>` defines the entity inside RSpec's top-level `:main` context. So, that second set of shared, "internal" examples weren't being defined inside 'foo', they were being defined at the top level. This confused things enough to trigger the RSpec warning as soon more than one other file `require_relative`'d the above code.

The fix was to just do `shared_examples 'bar'` in the nested set, not `RSpec.shared_examples 'bar'`, so that the inner examples were correctly described inside the inner context.

(Aside: This is an interesting example of how having monkey patching turned off is more important than might at first glance appear to be the case - it's not just for namespace purity. It allows for a much cleaner distinction in declarations between "this is top level" and "this is nested".)

Comment: Replacing RSpec.shared_examples with shared_examples worked for me where renaming the file did not